# Symmetric Matrices Help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following question.

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix.

a) Show that the matrix $B = A+A^T$ is symmetric.

Not sure how to do this. But here is my attempt. Well, let $A$ have a size of $n\times n$. That means $A^T$ must also have a size of $n$ by $n$ by the transpose property number of columns and rows are swapped. Therefore $B$ must also have a size $n$ by $n$. That's all I have at the moment.

b) Show that $C=AA^T$ is symmetric

I also have approached this like a) But not sure.

c) A matrix $M$ has a property that $M^T = - M$ (skew symmetry). Show that $D = (A - A^T)$ is a skew symmetric matrix.

d) Can you show how to write any square matrix as the sum of a symmetry and skew symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 2):

$$B^T = (A+A^T)^T=A^T+(A^T)^T=A+A^T=B$$$$C^T=(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T$$$$D ^T= (A - A^T)^T=A^T-(A^T)^T=A^T-(-A)^T=-A+A^T=-D$$$$\forall B :B=\frac{B+B^T}{2}+\frac{B-B^T}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks though, but I like to have an attempt. I was looking for a hint.

Comment: No worries thanks :-)

Comment: $\Huge\color{red}{+}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** use the definitions.

1. What does it mean for $B$ to be symmetric? It means $B^T=B$. Prove it.
2. Similar to 1.
3. Similar to 1.
4. Given a square matrix $\Omega$, note that $\Omega=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\Omega+\Omega^T+\Omega-\Omega^T\right)$. Try to extract the relevant matrices from this equality. (Use 1. and 3.)

Comment: 1. $B^T =  (A+A^T)^T$. Note I used this: $(\lambda A + \mu A^T)^T =  (\lambda A^T + \mu (A^T)^T).$ Now the transpose of that a transpose is just the matrix itself.

$= A^T + A.$ By the commutative law of matrix addition. We arrive $B^T = A + A^T = B.$ Hence symmetry occurs.

b) $C^T = (AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T=C.$

Is this right so far?

Comment: $D^T=(A-A^T)^T=A^T-A=-(A-A^T)=-D.$ Hence skew symmetry.

Comment: @Bobby Nice job.

Comment: Hey Git Gud. So I'm not sure what the question is asking for the last part. Isn't how you write a square matrix always $\frac{1}{2}$(symmetric matrix + skew symmetric matrix)? Do I need to do anything more to explain?

Comment: @Bobby I'm not sure I understand what you said just above, so I'll write something which will hopefully be helpful. Given a square matrix $\Omega$, you wish to find matrices $\Omega _1$ and $\Omega _2$ such that $\Omega=\Omega_1+\Omega _2$, where $\Omega _1$ is symmetric and $\Omega _2$ is a skew matrix. Now using the fact that $S$ is skew (respectively symmetric) if, and only if $(\forall \lambda \in \Bbb R)(\lambda S)$ is skew (respectively symmetric), you should be able to finish.

Answer (score 0):

$$B^T=(A+A^T)^T=A^T+A=B$$
$$C^T=(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T=C$$
Also, $D^T=-D^T$ as previous equalities. Finally,
$$A=\frac{A+A^T}{2}+\frac{A-A^T}{2}$$.

Comment: $A=A_1+A_2$, and as in previous inequalities, it is easy to check that $A_1$ is symmetric and $A_2$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: Thanks guys. Please I just want to have a crack for myself! :-) I just wanted a hint. Haha./